# Keeping python daemon alive

Tags: python, daemon

We develop some small services to run like unix daemons.

Our first implementation was dependent of twisted reactor. The reactor instance was our artifact to keep OS process alive and running without stop after subprocess call.

Recently, we removed Twisted dependencies for these modules, remaining the necessity to keep processes running after `subprocess` call. We put a '`while True: time.sleep(.1)`' statement in the end of our "main()" method and it works fine.

With the `time.sleep(.1)` call, our performance is wasting performance, considering wake up events ~600 times per minute. It's not a good for our application performance. If we replace

```
while True:
    time.sleep(.1)
```

by

```
while True:
    pass
```

it consumes so much CPU time (~1.7% of a i5, continually).

There are better or balanced alternative solutions with less CPU time occupation and with responsive performance for the following options?

```
reactor.run()
```

and

```
while True:
    time.sleep(.1)
```

I found some similar answers and discussions on stackoverflow and web, but did'n find a clear discussion about it considering python.

Comment: I would think that the sleep function actually don't waste performance. The sleep causes the process to suspend, so that the CPU can go and do other stuff in meantime. If there, however, is nothing to do but to execute you application, there is no such thing as "waste" anyway.

Comment: Sleep itself does not, but calling it 600 times a minute only contributes to the heat death of the universe.

Comment: Our application receives some stomp messages based on system events. Sometimes, it can receive a flush of messages. If I wakeup process just 600 times per minute, some messages will be so much delayed and accumulated for the next wakeup event. I think CPU time can be more efficient than 600 times per minute and give more time for the daemon than we force high level functions calls (time.sleep) to control it. That's one of my points

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the solution is to simply use a module that is...was* going to go into the standard library for this.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

apparently 3143 has been deferred, but the pypi link is to the implementation of the pep.

Comment: Good! I will try it and reply behavior results here. Thanks!

Comment: supervisord is great for OS level process management. Our issue is  doubt about some 'pythonic' way to not terminate script after its normal execution, keeping it alive waiting for system events.